# Mysql - find a table in all database

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Is there any command that I can locate a certain table from all databases? Since I forgot where the table is. Thanks.

Comment: "In all databases"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the [MySQL specific](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html):

```
SHOW TABLES
```

...or use the [ANSI standard, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html):

```
SELECT table_name,
       table_schema AS dbname
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_name='searched table name'
```

Comment: But in this way, I still don't know which database that table belongs to.

Comment: @Stan: I updated the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query to exist the database the table exists in.

Comment: WHERE table_name = 'my_table_name'

Comment: So if she knew what she wants then she could use the full query as :-   
SELECT table_name,
       table_schema AS dbname
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name='her_table_name'